does anyone know why I'm getting this error when I try to compile?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "spell.h"

#define MAX_CAPACITY  101

/*
Repeatedly read 2 strings from the user.
The strings must be separated by a space.
The program will compute the edit distance between them,
print the cost table, the cost and the alignment.

After that, read 2 file names (one for a dictionary file and
one for a file of misspelled words); find best matches for all the words in the test file
and get user's choice for fixing the word.
*/
int min(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (x < y && x < z)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else if (y < x && y < z)
    {
        return y;
    }
    else
    {
        return z;
    }
}


int edit_distance(char * first_string, char * second_string, int print_table)
{
    int first = strlen(first_string);
    int second = strlen(second_string);
    int* before = (int*)calloc(second + 1, sizeof(int));
    int* now = (int*)calloc(second + 1, sizeof(int));

    for (int x = 0; x <= second; x++)
    {
        before[x] = x;
    }
    for (int y = 1; y <= first; y++)
    {
        now[0] = y;
        for (int x = 1; x <= second; x++)
        {
            if (first_string[y - 1] == second_string[x - 1])
            {
                now[x] = before[x - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                int a = min(1 + before[x], 1 + now[x - 1], 1 + before[x - 1]);
                now[x] = a;
            }
        }
        memcpy(before, now, (second + 1) * sizeof(int));
    }
    int result = before[second];
    free(before);
    free(now);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // any word or file name can be at most 100 characters.
    char first[MAX_CAPACITY], second[MAX_CAPACITY];
    char dictname[MAX_CAPACITY], testname[MAX_CAPACITY];
    char c;    
    //int  printOn = 0;  // print-off

    // Part1: Compute and show edit distance for pairs of words  
    printf("\nPart 1 - edit distance table\n");  
    printf(" Repeatedly enter two words separated by a space (e.g.: cat someone).\n Stop with: -1 -1\n");
    while ( 1==1 ) {
        scanf("%s%s%c", first, second, &c);
        printf("\n first: %s",   first);
        printf("\nsecond: %s\n", second);
        if (strcmp(first,"-1") == 0 && strcmp(second,"-1") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        int dist = edit_distance(first, second, 1);  // last argument, 1, indicates that the distance table should be printed
        printf("edit distance: %d\n", dist);
        printf("\n=========================================================================================\n");
    }

    // Part2: read filenames and call spell-check
    printf("\nPart 2 - spell check\n");
    printf("Enter the dictionary file name: ");
    scanf("%s%c", dictname, &c);  // remove \n from read buffer
    printf("Enter the test file name: ");
    scanf("%s%c", testname, &c);  // remove \n from read buffer
    spell_check(testname, dictname);

    printf("\nGood bye!\n");
    return 0;
}



That's a linker error rather than a compilation error. The linker cannot find spell_check in a linked object or library. Where is that function?

You should include all your .c files during compilation
